# EC2 Wordpress instance SFTP connection failing to show wordpress files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, filezilla

Im very new to all of this.  I've successfully created an Amazon EC2 instance and installed wordpress.  I've used SFTP to successfully connect.  The problem now is that I cannot find any of the wordpress files.  I'm used to finding those files in the htdocs - but they do not appear to be there!  The site works great, and I can get into the wordpress backend - but I have several php files that need to be uploaded/changed.  Any help here is REALLY appreciated.

Attached is what I see when I successfully connect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not more than a minute after I asked, I found it!  Wordpress is under "apps"